# Обрезать строку в c#

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
string _track = ";123456789123?";
```

Как можно правильно обрезать строку чтобы от строки осталось `"89123"` ?

получить цифры стоящие перед вопросительным знаком в количестве 5...(получить последние 5 цифр без вопросительного знака)

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72407/discussion-on-question-by-igor-ilyichyov----c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать регулярное выражение, то оно банальное и короткое:

```
(\d{5})(?=\?)
```

Если на 100% уверены в том что вопросительный знак всегда есть в конце строки (именно конец строки, т.е. за знаком вопроса не будет никаких символов), можете использовать такое выражение:

```
\d{5}(?=\?$)
```

Так же, если вам не нужны строки с подобными данными к примеру: `89347?`, т.е. это всегда не начало строки, можно поставить проверку на то что данные не начинаются с 1го и по последний символ так:

```
(?!^)\d{5}(?=\?)
```

Имейте ввиду что такие строки, не будут включены в результат: `53333?`

Ну и напоследок, если необходимы все 3 проверки, т.е. 5 чисел, вопросительный знак, и не начало строки, то немного усложним выражение до такого вида:

```
(?!^)\d{5}(?=\??(?=$))
```

Ну а по данной ссылке можно посмотреть все варианты применения последнего из выражений: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/amk8e2/2)

Comment: Если есть другой способ, то предпочтительнее было бы использовать его, если нет то и этот не плох.

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov: Внесено исправление в выражение с отсечением вопросительного знака.

Comment: Все таки использовал Ваш метод.
Отдельное Спасибо!

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov а чем мой не подошёл?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Думаю как минимум тем, что ТС"у явно нужны целочисленные данные, но не просто строка состоящая из букв и чисел :)

Comment: Ну если для целей одновременной валидации, то логично. Просто могла быть ситуация где данные изначально однотипные, например то что логер генерирует, в этом случае может валидация и не нужна. Хотя в редкой ситуации логер может и какую-нибудь странную строчку выдать, и ваше решение реально такие строчки просто отбросит, так что соглашусь.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Yami прав, мне еще понадобилась валидация.

Comment: @Yami отдельное спасибо за остальные варианты...

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без регулярного выражения

```
string st = ";123456789123?";
string rez = st.Substring(st.Length-6,5);
```

В данном примере валидация на пример правильности ввода не проводится.

Comment: Вот мне как раз такое решение и нужно было. Спасибо большое!